How to get position data from acceleration data obtained from an IMU?
I was provided with a .bag file containing a recording in which a regular rectangular path (3m x 1.4m) is performed. My goal is to obtain a 3D plot of the trajectory taken by the IMU from the bag data. To this end, I have tried various direct double integration methods, including low-pass filters and Kalman filters, but I was unable to achieve an accurate estimate of the actual path taken. I also tried using ROS's robot_localization, but I find the YAML configuration process very counterintuitive, and I believe I was unable to set it up correctly.
If you have any ideas for obtaining an accurate trajectory without suffering too much from drift, or if you know how to configure robot_localization correctly for this purpose, please let me know. I am attaching the details of the .bag file and the MATLAB code for direct integration.
BAG FILE INFO:
rosbag info rectangle_path.bag

path:         rectangle_path.bag
version:      2.0
duration:     44.7s
start:        Aug 26 2024 17:15:08.71 (1724685308.71)
end:          Aug 26 2024 17:15:53.42 (1724685353.42)
size:         1.6 GB
messages:     12944
compression:  bz2 [1341/1341 chunks; 45.83%]
uncompressed: 3.5 GB @ 79.1 MB/s
compressed:   1.6 GB @ 36.3 MB/s (45.83%)

types:        realsense2_camera/IMUInfo  [a02adb3a99530b11ba18a16f40f9512a]
              realsense2_camera/Metadata [4966ca002be16ee67fe4dbfb2f354787]
              sensor_msgs/CameraInfo     [c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214]
              sensor_msgs/Image          [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
              sensor_msgs/Imu            [6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2]

topics:       /camera/accel/imu_info         1 msg     : realsense2_camera/IMUInfo 
              /camera/color/camera_info   1341 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo   
              /camera/color/image_raw     1340 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image   
              /camera/color/metadata      1340 msgs    : realsense2_camera/Metadata
              /camera/gyro/imu_info          1 msg     : realsense2_camera/IMUInfo 
              /camera/imu                 8921 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu

MATLAB CODE
% Caricamento del file bag
bag = rosbag('rectangle_path.bag');

% Selezione dei messaggi IMU
imu_msgs = select(bag, 'Topic', '/camera/imu');

% Lettura dei messaggi IMU
imu_data = readMessages(imu_msgs, 'DataFormat', 'struct');

% Numero di messaggi
num_msgs = length(imu_data);

% Preallocazione delle variabili
accel_x = zeros(num_msgs, 1);
accel_y = zeros(num_msgs, 1);
accel_z = zeros(num_msgs, 1);
gyro_x = zeros(num_msgs, 1);
gyro_y = zeros(num_msgs, 1);
gyro_z = zeros(num_msgs, 1);
timestamps = zeros(num_msgs, 1);

% Estrazione dei dati
for i = 1:num_msgs
    % Accelerazioni lineari
    accel_x(i) = imu_data{i}.LinearAcceleration.X;
    accel_y(i) = imu_data{i}.LinearAcceleration.Y;
    accel_z(i) = imu_data{i}.LinearAcceleration.Z;
    
    % Velocità angolari
    gyro_x(i) = imu_data{i}.AngularVelocity.X;
    gyro_y(i) = imu_data{i}.AngularVelocity.Y;
    gyro_z(i) = imu_data{i}.AngularVelocity.Z;
    
    % Timestamp
    timestamps(i) = double(imu_data{i}.Header.Stamp.Sec) + ...
                    double(imu_data{i}.Header.Stamp.Nsec)*1e-9;
end

% Allineamento dei timestamp all'inizio
timestamps = timestamps - timestamps(1);

% Frequenza di campionamento
fs = 1/mean(diff(timestamps));

% Filtro passa-basso per ridurre il rumore
cutoff = 5; % Frequenza di taglio in Hz
accel_x_filt = lowpass(accel_x, cutoff, fs);
accel_y_filt = lowpass(accel_y, cutoff, fs);
accel_z_filt = lowpass(accel_z, cutoff, fs);

% Rimozione della gravità (assumendo che agisca lungo Z)
g = 9.81; % Accelerazione gravitazionale in m/s^2
accel_z_filt = accel_z_filt - g;

% Integrazione per ottenere la velocità
velocity_x = cumtrapz(timestamps, accel_x_filt);
velocity_y = cumtrapz(timestamps, accel_y_filt);
velocity_z = cumtrapz(timestamps, accel_z_filt);

% Correzione della deriva della velocità
velocity_x = detrend(velocity_x);
velocity_y = detrend(velocity_y);
velocity_z = detrend(velocity_z);

% Integrazione per ottenere la posizione
position_x = cumtrapz(timestamps, velocity_x);
position_y = cumtrapz(timestamps, velocity_y);
position_z = cumtrapz(timestamps, velocity_z);

% Tracciamento del percorso in 2D
figure;
plot(position_x, position_y, 'LineWidth', 2);
title('Percorso stimato dall''IMU');
xlabel('Posizione X (m)');
ylabel('Posizione Y (m)');
axis equal;
grid on;

% Tracciamento del percorso in 3D (opzionale)
% figure;
% plot3(position_x, position_y, position_z, 'LineWidth', 2);
% title('Percorso stimato dall''IMU in 3D');
% xlabel('Posizione X (m)');
% ylabel('Posizione Y (m)');
% zlabel('Posizione Z (m)');
% grid on;

Also, how can I determine if the data in the .bag file was recorded correctly? Thanks for any help.

IMO, the double integration of acceleration data for position is pretty much never going to work well. Any biases will quickly turn into velocity data, which will send your position estimate flying off rapidly. There are very expensive IMUs out there that might be suitable, but generally, this won't work. robot_localization won't help here without some kind of velocity reference.
